# How to put a message on a Websphere MQ Queue from SQL Server sp?

Tags: sql-server, ibm-mq

Is there an API to connect to a Websphere MQ queue from an SQL Server stored procedure and put a message onto a queue?

If not, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution than that..Check this out.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fbc34040_.htm

Comment: That's great, thanks! This looks like a much better way of doing it, marking your answer as correct instead of my own.

Comment: Link has gone stale and the wayback machine doesn't have it. Any summary text?

Comment: @RichardWatson Did you manage to find it?

Comment: @tokfrans no, can’t remember what we did but I’m sure it was app level not in db

Answer (score 4):

The solution I am going to use for this is to write a CLR stored procedure and deploy this onto SQL Server.

Inside the CLR stored proc I will use the MQ .NET api.

**Update:** I created a stored proc using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using IBM.WMQ;

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static int MQStoredProc(String queueManager, String queueName, String messageText)
    {
        //MQEnvironment.Hostname = "localhost";
        //MQEnvironment.Port = 1414;
        //MQEnvironment.Channel = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";

        MQQueueManager mqQMgr = null;          // MQQueueManager instance
        MQQueue mqQueue = null;         // MQQueue instance

        try
        {
            mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager);
            mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);   // open queue for output but not if MQM stopping

            if (messageText.Length > 0)
            {
                // put the next message to the queue
                MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
                mqMsg.WriteString(messageText);
                mqMsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                MQPutMessageOptions mqPutMsgOpts = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                mqQueue.Put(mqMsg, mqPutMsgOpts);
            }

            return 0;
        }
        catch (MQException mqe)
        {
            return ((int)mqe.Reason);        
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mqQueue != null)
                mqQueue.Close();
            if (mqQMgr != null)
                mqQMgr.Disconnect();
        }
    }
};
```

This is not production ready but is inserting messages successfully on a queue manager running on the same server as the SQL server in bindings mode.

Comment: Neal, how did you register amqmdnet.dll in SqlServer ?
I've got this error:
Assembly 'amqmdnet' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.

The code is:
create assembly amqmdnet
from 'c:\mssql\assembly\amqmdnet.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to, write the information on to a file and then use rfhutil to export the message onto queue. This would require manual intervention. The other option would be to write a simple java application using JMS and JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET CLR approach would have been my suggestion, too. I'd be curious to see an example of the code, I've never tried that before! Should work I guess.

Comment: I tried out the clr method and it works well, added sample code to my answer if you want to see.

Comment: Were you able to deploy in prod env and did you have any hiccups?